# Java: how to store data triple in a list?

Tags: java

What's the best way in java to store data triple in a list ?

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
...
```

I usually use HashMap for couples of data key + value.. should I go for HashMap + Arraylist ? or ArrayList + ArrayList ?

thanks

Comment: Or create a new class that holds the three objects. What are you using it for?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
public class Triplet<T, U, V> {

    private final T first;
    private final U second;
    private final V third;

    public Triplet(T first, U second, V third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public T getFirst() { return first; }
    public U getSecond() { return second; }
    public V getThird() { return third; }
}
```

And to instantiate the list:

```
List<Triplet<String, Integer, Integer>> = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: You should make `a`, `b` and `c` final.

Comment: equals and hashCode could be not bad here

Comment: Why make getters if a,b,c aren't private?

Comment: @SteveKuo why it must be final?

Comment: @AmiHollander in a previous edit, the fields were not private. now it is a bit redundant, but maybe still good for conveying that they are final (instead of implying from lack of setters).

Comment: AutoValue is your friend here: https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md It'll allow you to trivially make structural objects like this which are typesafe and get hashing, comparison, immutability etc for free.

Answer (score 9):

```
public class Triple<F, S, T> {

    public final F first;
    public final S second;
    public final T third;

    public Triple(F first, S second, T third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Triple)) {
            return false;
        }
        Triple<?, ?, ?> p = (Triple<?, ?, ?>) o;
        return first.equals(p.first) && second.equals(p.second) && third.equals(p.third);
    }

    private static boolean equals(Object x, Object y) {
        return (x == null && y == null) || (x != null && x.equals(y));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (first == null ? 0 : first.hashCode()) ^ (second == null ? 0 : second.hashCode()) ^ (third == null ? 0 : third.hashCode());
    }

    public static <F, S, T> Triple <F, S, T> create(F f, S s, T t) {
        return new Triple<F, S, T>(f, s, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is easy to find collision for this class's hashCode method. Consider creating three instances (<Integer, Integer, Integer>). First with [1,0,0], second with [0,1,0], third with [0,0,1]. All of them will have hashCode equal to one, even though they are different triplets.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Triple](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) and [ImmutableTriple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutableTriple.html) without dependences of imports of Apache's code. L, M, and R types must implement interface Comparable.

Triple.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * <p>A triple consisting of three elements.</p>
 * <p/>
 * <p>This class is an abstract implementation defining the basic API. It refers to the elements as
 * 'left', 'middle' and 'right'.</p>
 * <p/>
 * <p>Subclass implementations may be mutable or immutable. However, there is no restriction on the
 * type of the stored objects that may be stored. If mutable objects are stored in the triple, then
 * the triple itself effectively becomes mutable.</p>
 *
 * @param <L>
 *         the left element type
 * @param <M>
 *         the middle element type
 * @param <R>
 *         the right element type
 *
 * @version $Id: Triple.java 1557584 2014-01-12 18:26:49Z britter $
 * @since 3.2
 */
public abstract class Triple<L, M, R>
        implements Comparable<Triple<L, M, R>>, Serializable
{

    /**
     * Serialization version
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * <p>Obtains an immutable triple of from three objects inferring the generic types.</p>
     * <p/>
     * <p>This factory allows the triple to be created using inference to obtain the generic
     * types.</p>
     *
     * @param <L>
     *         the left element type
     * @param <M>
     *         the middle element type
     * @param <R>
     *         the right element type
     * @param left
     *         the left element, may be null
     * @param middle
     *         the middle element, may be null
     * @param right
     *         the right element, may be null
     *
     * @return a triple formed from the three parameters, not null
     */
    public static <L, M, R> Triple<L, M, R> of(
            final L left,
            final M middle,
            final R right)
    {
        return new ImmutableTriple<L, M, R>(left, middle, right);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


    /**
     * <p>Gets the left element from this triple.</p>
     *
     * @return the left element, may be null
     */
    public abstract L getLeft();

    /**
     * <p>Gets the middle element from this triple.</p>
     *
     * @return the middle element, may be null
     */
    public abstract M getMiddle();

    /**
     * <p>Gets the right element from this triple.</p>
     *
     * @return the right element, may be null
     */
    public abstract R getRight();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


    /**
     * <p>Compares the triple based on the left element, followed by the middle element, finally the
     * right element. The types must be {@code Comparable}.</p>
     *
     * @param other
     *         the other triple, not null
     *
     * @return negative if this is less, zero if equal, positive if greater
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Triple<L, M, R> other)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // assume this can be done; if not throw CCE as per Javadoc
        final Comparable<Object> comparableLeft = (Comparable<Object>) getLeft();
        int cmpLeft = comparableLeft.compareTo(other.getLeft());

        if (cmpLeft != 0) {
            return cmpLeft;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // assume this can be done; if not throw CCE as per Javadoc
        final Comparable<Object> comparableMidle = (Comparable<Object>) getMiddle();
        int cmpMidle = comparableMidle.compareTo(other.getMiddle());

        if (cmpMidle != 0) {
            return cmpMidle;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // assume this can be done; if not throw CCE as per Javadoc
        final Comparable<Object> comparableRight = (Comparable<Object>) getRight();
        int cmpRight = comparableRight.compareTo(other.getRight());

        return cmpRight;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Compares this triple to another based on the three elements.</p>
     *
     * @param obj
     *         the object to compare to, null returns false
     *
     * @return true if the elements of the triple are equal
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Triple<?, ?, ?>) {
            final Triple<?, ?, ?> other = (Triple<?, ?, ?>) obj;


            return equals(getLeft(), other.getLeft()) &&
                    equals(getMiddle(), other.getMiddle()) &&
                    equals(getRight(), other.getRight());
        }
        return false;
    }


    private boolean equals(
            final Object object1,
            final Object object2)
    {
        return !(object1 == null || object2 == null) &&
                (object1 == object2 || object1.equals(object2));
    }


    /**
     * <p>Returns a suitable hash code.</p>
     *
     * @return the hash code
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return (getLeft() == null ? 0 : getLeft().hashCode()) ^
                (getMiddle() == null ? 0 : getMiddle().hashCode()) ^
                (getRight() == null ? 0 : getRight().hashCode());
    }


    /**
     * <p>Returns a String representation of this triple using the format {@code
     * ($left, $middle, $right)}.</p>
     *
     * @return a string describing this object, not null
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return new StringBuilder().append('(')
                .append(getLeft())
                .append(',')
                .append(getMiddle())
                .append(',')
                .append(getRight())
                .append(')')
                .toString();
    }


    /**
     * <p>Formats the receiver using the given format.</p>
     * <p/>
     * <p>This uses {@link java.util.Formattable} to perform the formatting. Three variables may be
     * used to embed the left and right elements. Use {@code %1$s} for the left element, {@code
     * %2$s} for the middle and {@code %3$s} for the right element. The default format used by
     * {@code toString()} is {@code (%1$s,%2$s,%3$s)}.</p>
     *
     * @param format
     *         the format string, optionally containing {@code %1$s}, {@code %2$s} and {@code %3$s},
     *         not null
     *
     * @return the formatted string, not null
     */
    public String toString(final String format)
    {
        return String.format(format, getLeft(), getMiddle(), getRight());
    }
}
```

ImmutableTriple.java

```
public final class ImmutableTriple<L, M, R> extends Triple<L, M, R> {

    /** Serialization version */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** Left object */
    public final L left;
    /** Middle object */
    public final M middle;
    /** Right object */
    public final R right;

    /**
     * <p>Obtains an immutable triple of from three objects inferring the generic types.</p>
     *
     * <p>This factory allows the triple to be created using inference to
     * obtain the generic types.</p>
     *
     * @param <L> the left element type
     * @param <M> the middle element type
     * @param <R> the right element type
     * @param left  the left element, may be null
     * @param middle  the middle element, may be null
     * @param right  the right element, may be null
     * @return a triple formed from the three parameters, not null
     */
    public static <L, M, R> ImmutableTriple<L, M, R> of(final L left, final M middle, final R right) {
        return new ImmutableTriple<L, M, R>(left, middle, right);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new triple instance.
     *
     * @param left  the left value, may be null
     * @param middle the middle value, may be null
     * @param right  the right value, may be null
     */
    public ImmutableTriple(final L left, final M middle, final R right) {
        super();
        this.left = left;
        this.middle = middle;
        this.right = right;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public L getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public M getMiddle() {
        return middle;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public R getRight() {
        return right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you expect track four or more objects together, look for something that scales.

If you were to decide you want the notion of a Triple, to get some ideas you can follow Sun's pattern for [javac.util.Pair](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/javac/util/Pair.java):

```
public class Pair<A, B> {

    public final A fst;
    public final B snd;

    public Pair(A fst, B snd) {
        this.fst = fst;
        this.snd = snd;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Pair[" + fst + "," + snd + "]";
    }

    private static boolean equals(Object x, Object y) {
        return (x == null && y == null) || (x != null && x.equals(y));
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return
            other instanceof Pair<?,?> &&
            equals(fst, ((Pair<?,?>)other).fst) &&
            equals(snd, ((Pair<?,?>)other).snd);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        if (fst == null) return (snd == null) ? 0 : snd.hashCode() + 1;
        else if (snd == null) return fst.hashCode() + 2;
        else return fst.hashCode() * 17 + snd.hashCode();
    }

    public static <A,B> Pair<A,B> of(A a, B b) {
        return new Pair<A,B>(a,b);
    }
}
```

or follow Google's [android.util.Pair](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/util/Pair.java)

```
public class Pair<F, S> {
    public final F first;
    public final S second;

    public Pair(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
        final Pair<F, S> other;
        try {
            other = (Pair<F, S>) o;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return first.equals(other.first) && second.equals(other.second);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + first.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + second.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to agree with whirlwin.

The general consensus, although I can't find the evidence now, stipulates that parametrized types should be no more than 2. This is why every class I can think of in the Java collections library has at max two parametrized types.

Code becomes cluttered when you have three parametrized types. Just way too many >,< to deal with.

I suggest what whirlwin said and create an object that holds the three specific types you need.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has implemented a class called Triple:

```
/**
 * Represents a triad of values
*
* There is no meaning attached to values in this class, it can be used for any purpose.
* Triple exhibits value semantics, i.e. two triples are equal if all three components are equal.
* An example of decomposing it into values:
* @sample samples.misc.Tuples.tripleDestructuring
*
* @param A type of the first value.
* @param B type of the second value.
* @param C type of the third value.
* @property first First value.
* @property second Second value.
* @property third Third value.
*/

public data class Triple<out A, out B, out C>(
   public val first: A,
   public val second: B,
   public val third: C
) : Serializable {

   /**
    * Returns string representation of the [Triple] including its [first],    [second] and [third] values.
    */
   public override fun toString(): String = "($first, $second, $third)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Groovy, it can be simplified to:

```
@Canonical
class Triple<F,M,T> {
    final F first
    final M middle
    final T last
}

// Usage:
def triple = new Triple<Integer, Double, String>(100, 2.5, "Hello")
println triple.first        // Out: 100
assert triple == new Triple<Integer, Double, String>(100, 2.50, "Hello") // true
```

`@Canonical` annotation takes care of creating the constructor matching your fields and Groovy takes care of the rest.