# List of tuples in Android?

Tags: java, android, tuples

I do not find possibility of "list of tuples" in Java. What alternative structure do you suggest where  can be stored in a list / array?

In other languages like in Swift, declaring it looks like this:

```
var items: [(id: String, text: String, totalMatch: Int16)] = [];
```

I would avoid declaring a class, fields.

Comment: Hm. A class would be the easiest way to get that. A matrix would also be possible `Object[][] tuples` or with `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how to store data triple in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010843/java-how-to-store-data-triple-in-a-list)

Answer (score -1):

**SQL**
I don't know what you really want to do. But if you want to manage Data you could use a sql liste Database provided per dafault by android. 
Your Objects would be stored very lightweight but you have to give a lot of effort. 

**Class/ArrayList**
Otherwise just use a ArrayList. Until you dont have more than 10000 Items its no Problem even on older Devices. 
You will need two classes.

```
class Item{
   String id; 
   String text; 
   int totalMatch;
}
class YourClass{
   ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

**JSON Parser**
Very good and easy parser for JSON Files is GSON from Google:
 See:
https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score -1):

Old question but if anyone still in need of, possibly you can try `Pair` class from `android.util` package inside List. Something like this:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> myPairList = new ArrayList<>();
```